# Working with Apache.POI and getting an error message only when running it from a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to work with an XLS spreadsheet file and then to generate an DOCX word document.  The program runs fine on its own, but I get an error message when running it from a jar.

Here are the details.  The program compiles successfully with:

```
javac -classpath poi-3.10.1/*;poi-3.10.1/ooxml-lib/*;commons-io-2.4/*;commons-lang3-3.3.2/*;guava-libaries/*;MigLayout-4.0/*;.  reviewReport.java
```

The program runs successfully with:

```
java -classpath poi-3.10.1/*;poi-3.10.1/ooxml-lib/*;commons-io-2.4/*;commons-lang3-3.3.2/*;guava-libaries/*;MigLayout-4.0/*;. reviewReport
```

I set up this manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Class-Path: poi-3.10.1/*;poi-3.10.1/ooxml-lib/*;commons-io-2.4/*;commons-lang3-3.3.2/*;guava-libaries/*;MigLayout-4.0/*;.  
  Main-Class: reviewReport
```

(There is a blank line at the bottom of the manifest file)

Creating the jar works successfully with:

```
jar cfm reviewReport.jar manifest.mf *.class
```

I try to run the program from the jar with this command:

```
java -classpath poi-3.10.1/*;poi-3.10.1/ooxml-lib/*;commons-io-2.4/*;commons-lang3-3.3.2/*;guava-libaries/*;MigLayout-4.0/*;.  -jar reviewReport.jar
```

But instead of running, I get these error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.openxm
l4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:430)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1061)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:506)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:498)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions
.InvalidFormatException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:665)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:942)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:851)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:827)
        ... 5 more
```

I am trying to understand what causes a program that I can run on its own not to be able to run from a jar, when I use the same classpath in building that jar.  After researching it it seemed like the problem might be due to one of two things:  (1) Trying to use POI's code that handles XLS and DOC files on a file that is actually XLSX or DOCX (or vice versa), or (2) the class loader not finding the InvalidFormatException class during runtime.

I've looked at both potential problems.  For (1), my program process a XLS spreadsheet.  I've gone through the code and I believe I correctly always use the HSSF classes from POI.  My program then creates a DOCX word document.  I've gone through the code and I believe it always correctly uses XWPF classes for that.

For (2), when I use the verbose class feature discussed in the article at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dclp1/index.html, the command to run the program is:

```
java -Dibm.cl.verbose=org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException -classpath poi-3.10.1/*;poi-3.10.1/ooxml-lib/*;commons-io-2.4/*;commons-lang3-3.3.2/*;guava-libaries/*;MigLayout-4.0/*;.  reviewSearchReport
```

The system shows how the class loader searches for that class in the various locations.  It ends with this successful statement:

```
AppClassLoader found org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException.
class in \poi-3.10.1\poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar

AppClassLoader found org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
```

But I get a different result when I run it from the jar.  The command

```
java -Dibm.cl.verbose=org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException -classpath poi-3.10.1/*;poi-3.10.1/ooxml-lib/*;commons-io-2.4/*;commons-lang3-3.3.2/*;guava-libaries/*;MigLayout-4.0/*;.  -jar reviewReport.jar
```

And here is what displays:

```
AppClassLoader attempting to find org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFor
matException

AppClassLoader using classpath C:\reviewReport.jar

AppClassLoader could not find org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatE
xception.class in C:\reviewReport.jar

AppClassLoader could not find org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatE
xception
```

Can someone point me in the proper direction?  Do I have a class loader problem here or does the code in my program incorrectly the POI (such as the classes for DOCX being used on a DOC file, or the ones for XLSX being used on an XLS file)?

Comment: `...Exception.class in C:\revieReport.jar` is this a typo in your AppClassLoader snippet? Or does it actually say `revieREport`?

Comment: I fixed the text to "reviewReport.jar".  That's actually a simplified name of my program and jar to make it easier to read here.

Comment: Aren't `-classpath` and `-jar` mutually exclusive options to the JVM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Gagravarr, I discovered that the jar command doesn't use the "-classpath" argument (although you don't get an error if you include it in the command line).

More importantly, the Class-Path section of the manifest.mf file uses a space to separate the items instead of the semi-colon (";") used to separate the items when using the "-classpath" argument in the javac statement.

I changed my manifest.mf file to separate the items in the Class-Path section and I also listed the jars specifically instead of relying on "poi-3.10.1/*" wildcard formatting.